# Why isn't my meteor template being reactively rendered?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template helper like so

```
Template.index.allUpcomingGames = function() {
    return Games.find({date: {$gte: new Date()}}, {sort: {date: 1}});
};
```

So if I'm reading the docs right the template should be re-rendered whenever this query result changes.

The actual behaviour I'm seeing is that when i first load the page (empty minimongo cache) the template renders no results. When an incremental change is detected and the template is forcibly rerendered the items magically appear, so presumably the initial page load is happening before the query returns, and subsequently not reactively re-rendering as I would expect. What am I doing wrong? What is best practice for managing template dependencies on queries?

#### update - pub/sub info

Should have included pub/subs. Very simple I'm just publishing everything at the minute although once this is working it will get smarter. I have removed autopublish package.

publish

```
Meteor.publish("allGames", function(userId) {
    return Games.find();
});
```

subscribe

```
Meteor.subscribe("allGames", this.userId);
```

As you can see I'm not using the userId yet

#### update 2 - minimal test case

I've simplified this to something reproducible, it looks like there's a fundamental misunderstanding about collections on my part. I've put together 3 test cases here:

https://github.com/antiBaconMachine/meteorCollectionRenderingTests

The output I see for the 3 tests is

1. No Games
2. a count, followed by records equal to the number of times the meteor server has been started
3. no games

I would expect the first test to render reactively as `forEach` should fetch the documents which I had assumed was being called by handlebars `{{#each}}`.From the meteor docs:

> Cursors are a reactive data source. The first time you retrieve a cursor's documents with fetch, map, or forEach inside a reactive computation (eg, a template or autorun), Meteor will register a dependency on the underlying data.

The second test works as I would expect which confuses me as the only difference is that I retrieve the count.

I'm assuming the last test fails as I'm fetching the documents before they are ready and once retrieved the query is no longer reactive? That is just a guess.

Any insight into this would be appreciated I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Is that the exact query you're using? You don't have to do anything but use the query as you expect. The dependencies are automatically managed.

Comment: What about your publish/subscribe methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: the initial answer and the bug reproduction that followed it are completely different. The one helped to spot another. Looks for the second part of this answer for real information.

**Answer to the initial question:**

This behavior makes sense to me:

Let's look at your query:

```
Games.find({date: {$gte: new Date()}}, {sort: {date: 1}})
```

You are looking for all games, sorted by date whose date is **greater than** the date the **query** is **created**.

So let's say you have following items in the database:

```
A, date: 100
B, date: 200
C, date: 300
```

Your client js is loaded and the current time is `350`. Your query is created as `Games.find({ date: {$gte: 350} }, {sort: {date: 1}});`. Surely A, B and C are behind `350` date and thus are not rendered.

Then you insert a new game into database, say `D, date: 400`. Yes, it should appear be returned by the query that looks at everything created after `350`.

What behavior do you expect?

**Additions to updates:**

This is a bug.

This bug was filed for the shark rendering engine. New engine (spark) has this issue solved and will be released in the next Meteor release. (maybe 0.7)

The bug happens when you pass a minimongo cursor as a template data context. It's very unusual way to get data to templates. I think that's why it existed for so long but was not spotted.

The temporary workaround is to not pass cursors as data context. Instead you can pass id or name or anything else and then have a separate template helper for callee template that returns an appropriate cursor.

A funny thing: instead of passing cursor to a template you can embed it into #with block helper and it will work as expected:

```
{{#with games}}
      <ul>
        {{#if this.count}}
            {{#each this}}
            <li class="u-margin--sm">
                <a href="/game/show/{{_id}}" class="col-md-8">{{name}}</a>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        {{else}}
        <span class="t-small">No games</span>
        {{/if}}
    </ul>
{{/with}}
```

And everything works :).

Re: withFetch

It works as expected if you use `length` instead of `count`. When you fetch, cursor returns a plain JS array, it doesn't have a `count` property but has `length`.

Comment: Dates on the games will be in the future, say next week for example so I expect these games to be returned. They are returned if I use this query directly on mongo console or if the template is otherwise re-rendered e.g. by code redeploy.

Comment: @OllieEdwards interesting. A minimal reproduction and a ticket on GitHub are welcome (if you think it is a bug).

Comment: Yeah I think a minimal case is required here, I'll put one together. I mainly asked the question as a sanity check, glad it looks like my understanding of the docs was ok, must be something else in the stack.

Comment: Simple reproducing test cases added, I'm even more confused, any insight appreciated.

Comment: @OllieEdwards: updated my answer. TL;DR: fixed in trunk, will be released in a next major version.

Comment: Interesting. It seems the workaround only works if the with block calls the helper directly, we can't do {{#with this}} which is a shame but I guess if this is fixed in trunk then fine. One query though, the findWithFetch test is not passing a cursor as the results are fetched so how come that one doesn't work?

Comment: The last paragraph of my answer explains why findWithFetch doesn't work: since the result is fetched (which means plain old javascript array), it doesn't have the `count` property. Arrays only have `length` property. If you replace count with length, findAndFetch test will pass